# NO DATA FOUND in loop cursor

Tags: loops, plsql, cursor

I got 'No data found' error when I ran the following codes in PLSQL.

```
 declare

    v_firm_id number;
    amount number;

    begin

    OPEN MT_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT firm_id
    FROM t_firm;

    LOOP

    FETCH MT_CURSOR INTO v_firm_id;

    EXIT WHEN MT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

    Select sum(TRN_AMOUNT) into amount 
    from t_sales
    where FIRM_ID = v_firm_id;

    update t_firm
    set matching_amount = amount
    where firm_id = v_firm_id; 

    END LOOP;


 end;
```

Anything wrong with this codes? Could anyone let me know the correction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is there is no data in the table T_SALES for one of the firms returned by the cursor.  To handle this you need to include an handler for the NO_DATA_FOUND 
exception so that if there are not sales transactions for a customer the total sales amount is set to zero:

```
declare
  v_firm_id number;
  amount number;

begin
  OPEN MT_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT firm_id
    FROM t_firm;

  LOOP
    FETCH MT_CURSOR INTO v_firm_id;

    EXIT WHEN MT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

    BEGIN
      Select sum(TRN_AMOUNT) into amount 
        from t_sales
        where FIRM_ID = v_firm_id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        AMOUNT := 0;
    END;

    update t_firm
      set matching_amount = amount
      where firm_id = v_firm_id; 

  END LOOP;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: hi I could get sum(trn_amount) from that query if i run separately. I tried to print the amount as follow:
  dbms_output.put_line('amount: ' || amount);
I got the output as follow: (by right if no transaction sales it will show 0 but seems like it's null)
  amount: (BLANK)

Comment: Change `Select sum(TRN_AMOUNT) into amount` to `Select NVL(sum(TRN_AMOUNT), 0) into amount`.

Answer (score 0):

> hi I could get sum(trn_amount) from that query if i run separately. I
>   tried to print the amount as follow: dbms_output.put_line('amount: '
>   || amount); I got the output as follow: (by right if no transaction
>   sales it will show 0 but seems like it's null) amount: (BLANK)

I guess there is no match between t_firm and t_sales based on firm_id.

A small hint, replace it with a SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE t_firm  ( matching_amount NUMBER, firm_id NUMBER );

CREATE TABLE t_sales ( trn_amount NUMBER, firm_id NUMBER );

INSERT INTO  t_firm  VALUES (100, 1);

INSERT INTO  t_sales VALUES (200, 1);

UPDATE  t_firm f
SET     f.matching_amount =
        (
            SELECT sum(s.trn_amount)
            FROM t_sales s
            WHERE f.firm_id = s.firm_id
        )
;

SELECT matching_amount FROM t_firm WHERE firm_id = 1;
-- 200
```